# How do I put GIS points (.shp format) on a GIS map?

Tags: anylogic

I have been having a problem for two days now. When I want to extract a QGIS layer in the format (.shp) to AnyLogic, the polygon layer works, the line layer works.

However, the layer of my points does not work. I paid attention to my projection (WGS 84), and when I add my points in the "shapefiles" section it is not displayed.

If anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your GISMap in the editor, then select `Convert Shapefile to Space Markup`. A popup window will open which will allow you to select the shapefile with your points. Then, in the `Convert to:` dropdown menu, select `GIS Markup`. Make sure `Convert Points` is true, then hit OK. This will add a GIS Point to your map for each of the points in your shapefile.

[image: Popup Window]

[image: Points Added]

Comment: TYVM !! I had indeed forgotten this step